# Commit To Multiple Databases In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html mentions nesting some transaction blocks using models associated with the various databases as a workaround. Yet that doesn't work in my case. Perhaps because my models are monkey patched together.

Comment: *that doesn't work in my case* -- could you expand on this? why does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

I've found two solutions:

- establish_connection("#{Rails.env}") within the non-committal model
- MyNoncommittalModel.connection.execute("COMMIT")

Both feel like a hack.